# Make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over a slider

Tags: css, cursor

The home page of https://ilanwittenberg.com/ displays a full-screen slider. Unfortunately, some PC users fail to click on the screen to move onto the Portfolio page: https://ilanwittenberg.com/portfolio/

Is there a way to change the cursor from an arrow to a hand when the mouse hovers above a slider on that page only (when using a PC)?

The code below did not work:

```
.wcp-caption-plugin .image-caption-box {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

The home page contains the following Code Block:

```
html{
overflow:hidden;
}
body{
cursor:pointer !important;
}
#fullscreen_slider_0{
z-index:0;
}
#wpadminbar{
display: none !important;
}
.content, .container{
padding: 0 !important;
min-height: 0 !important;
}
#top.avia-blank #main .container_wrap:first-child{
border: none !important;
}
#top.avia-blank #wrap_all #main{
border: none !important;
}
```

Should I make changes to this code?

The expected result is that the mouse cursor will change from an arrow to a hand when hovering above the full-screen slider showing on the homepage.

Comment: The home page contains the following Code Block:

    html{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    body{
    cursor:pointer !important;
    }
    #fullscreen_slider_0{
    z-index:0;
    }
    #wpadminbar{
    display: none !important;
    }
    .content, .container{
    padding: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    }
    #top.avia-blank #main .container_wrap:first-child{
    border: none !important;
    }
    #top.avia-blank #wrap_all #main{
    border: none !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

`.wcp-caption-plugin .image-caption-box` dont appear to exist on that page. Try adding that rule to `.splash-logo`

Comment: Have modified the splash-logo Code Block to:
    <div>
     <img src="http://ilanwittenberg.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Ilan-Wittenberg- 
     Logo-v5.gif" alt="Ilan Wittenberg Auckland Photographer of the Year" />
    .wcp-caption-plugin .image-caption-box
    </div>
Is this the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo-classes on CSS :

```
.wcp-caption-plugin:hover .image-caption-box:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Or separate the classes if needed :

```
.wcp-caption-plugin:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.image-caption-box:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Matheus!
The home page contains the following Code Block:

    html{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    body{
    cursor:pointer !important;
    }
    #fullscreen_slider_0{
    z-index:0;
    }
    #wpadminbar{
    display: none !important;
    }
    .content, .container{
    padding: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    }
    #top.avia-blank #main .container_wrap:first-child{
    border: none !important;
    }
    #top.avia-blank #wrap_all #main{
    border: none !important;
    }

Should I make changes to this code?

Comment: You're welcome !  Would you kindly accept my answer as the best answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with the following css code:

```
.splash-logo:hover {
cursor: pointer !important; 
}
```